# PHP: turn array values into string variables

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

I have a super simple array that I need to turn into individual string/integer variables. Eg:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 507 [2] => 203 ) )
```

Should result in

```
$value1 = 35
$value2 = 507
$value3 = 203
```

I'm sure this is pretty simple but I've looked at implode and it seems to concatenate the arrays into a single string, whereas I need each value as a separate variable. Have also tried foreach but come unstuck. Anyone know how to do this?

I can't seem to use $array[0][0] (=35) as I'm putting these variables into a MySQLi query and keep getting errors when I do it this way.

Thanks!

Comment: use php  extract

Comment: `$array[0][0]`, `$array[0][1]`, etc. And you don't need individual variables.

Comment: share you error as well.

Comment: i gave hint to him . extract have parameter too . he need to check that all to get  what he need .  @BunkerBoy

Comment: thanks @jYoThi i got it....

Answer (score 2):

```
extract($array[0], EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "value"); 
// $value_1, $value_2, $value_3 are available
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 2):

Use php `list()` function like:

```
$arr = array( 0 => array ( 0 => 35, 1 => 507, 2 => 203 ) ) ;
list($a, $b, $c) = $arr[0];
echo $a.' : '.$b.' : '.$c;
```

[Working Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38bc748d138b0ccc801e702a5ac32c95b7ad27f7)

[Php List Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: Sounds great!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Used extract and it works perfectly now for my query. Thanks all.

```
extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "custom");
extract($custom_0, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "custom2");
echo "Array item 1 is " . $custom2_0;
echo "Array item 2 is " . $custom2_1;
echo "Array item 3 is " . $custom2_2;
```